# C development under NETBEANS, cc1

Tags: c, netbeans, mingw

I installed netbeans to write code in C. But there is problem using Mingw compilers. It works just fine, till i try to run the project.
First it was unable to find cc1.exe while trying to run it. When i found it and manually copied into the same folder there is just another error.

```
"C:/bin/make.exe" -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk QMAKE= SUBPROJECTS= .build-conf
C:\bin\make.exe[1]: Entering directory `D:/1/2/Skola/IZP/programovani/projekt4netbeans/CppApplication_6'
"C:/bin/make.exe"  -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk dist/Debug/MinGW_1-Windows/cppapplication_6.exe
C:\bin\make.exe[2]: Entering directory `D:/1/2/Skola/IZP/programovani/projekt4netbeans/CppApplication_6'
mkdir -p build/Debug/MinGW_1-Windows
rm -f build/Debug/MinGW_1-Windows/main.o.d
gcc.exe    -c -g -MMD -MP -MF build/Debug/MinGW_1-Windows/main.o.d -o build/Debug/MinGW_1-Windows/main.o main.c
cc1: error: command line option '-lang-c' is valid for the driver but not for C
C:\bin\make.exe[2]: *** [build/Debug/MinGW_1-Windows/main.o] Error 1
C:\bin\make.exe[2]: Leaving directory `D:/1/2/Skola/IZP/programovani/projekt4netbeans/CppApplication_6'
C:\bin\make.exe[1]: *** [.build-conf] Error 2
C:\bin\make.exe[1]: Leaving directory `D:/1/2/Skola/IZP/programovani/projekt4netbeans/CppApplication_6'
C:\bin\make.exe: *** [.build-impl] Error 2

BUILD FAILED (exit value 2, total time: 2s)
```

if someone could help me with that.. thanks :)

Comment: You should be using MinGW tools from the MinGW command line.

Comment: how to do that please? I am new in this...

Answer (score 0):

Make shure you have current versions of Netbeans and MinGw and that you have a correct installation ([Configuring the NetBeans IDE for C/C++/Fortran](http://netbeans.org/community/releases/72/cpp-setup-instructions.html)).

On mingw you **should not use** `make` from `mingw/bin`, but the one from `msys` (**`<mingw>/msys/1.0/bin/make.exe`**)